# Passing generic type parameters to Knexjs insert

Tags: typescript, knex.js, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a database generic model to base my other models off.
When making a `create` function I ran into the problem of `Knex.js`'s `insert` function requires a argument with the type of:

```js
TRecord extends CompositeTableType<unknown>
        ? ResolveTableType<TRecord, 'insert'> | ReadonlyArray<ResolveTableType<TRecord, 'insert'>>
        : DbRecordArr<TRecord> | ReadonlyArray<DbRecordArr<TRecord>>
```

I'm trying to pass the data in from my function:

```js
async create(data: TTableAttributes){
    await this.knex.insert(data).returning("*").then((data) => { console.log(data); return data; });
}
    }
```

Is there some way of transforming my parameter into the `CompositeTableType` so that it will work?
I have checked the documentation under Typescript Support and there's almost nothing about `insert` with Typescript.